# Set accessibilityLabel on UIMenuItem

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, voiceover, uimenuitem

I am trying to set the `accessibilityLabel` of a `UIMenuItem` and it seems to have no effect. VoiceOver simply reads the title of the item no matter what:

```
    let foo = UIMenuItem(title: "foo", action: #selector(doSomething))
    item.isAccessibilityElement = true
    item.accessibilityLabel = "bar"
```

For this item, VoiceOver reads "foo" instead of "bar."  Also, the `accessibilityHint` seems to be ignored as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UIMenuItem` element is actually a `UICalloutBarButton` private class containing a `UIButtonLabel` *(iOS 13)* and, as is, **you can't custom its a11y properties** even if you can easily code it *(informal protocol)*.
That's insane because, in order to vend an a11y app, you MUST adapt it to the users and that's definitely not the case here.

However, a workaround may be implemented as follows to reach your goal:

- Render the menu controller inaccessible *(a11yTraits = .none)*.
- Get the menu controller frame *(`menuFrame` property)* for the next step.
- Create an accessible element that wraps the menu when displayed *(`UIAccessibilityElement` init + `accessibilityFrameInContainerSpace`)*.
- For this new accessible element, create [a11y custom actions](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#custom-actions) that match each element of the [menuItems] ⟹ here you can provide the VoiceOver label.

It would have been better to create an accessible element for each menuItem *(and then provide a better customization)* but I didn't find out the way to get the frame of each individual item.

And, unfortunately, this problem is still current for the last 3 years.

⚠️ ⬛️◼️▪️ **EDIT**  ▪️◼️⬛️ ⚠️ *(2020/03/19)*

I wrote a **D**eveloper **T**echnical **S**upport **I**ncident *(no 731229763)* for this problem and here's the answer from Apple:

> Our engineers have reviewed your request and have determined that you are experiencing a known issue for which there is no known workaround at this time.

I submitted a bug report entitled **VoiceOver: accessibilityLabel can't be implemented on a UIMenuItem element** with the reference **FB7623526**.

Now, you know why **accessibilityLabel is useless and without effects on a UIMenuItem element**.