# How to read a value from MenuItem in XCUITest?

Tags: swift, menuitem, xctest, xcuitest

I have a menu item that looks like a checkbox:

[image]

I would like to click/not-click on it depending on the current value. **How do I get the current value?**

My code for accessing and clicking it looks like this:

```
let menuBars = application.menuBars
let outlineModeMenuItem = menuBars.menuItems["outline_mode"]
outlineModeMenuItem.click()
```

The element structure looks like this:

```
Attributes: MenuItem, {{0.0, 401.0}, {220.0, 22.0}}, identifier: 'outline_mode', title: 'Outline Mode', Disabled
Element subtree:
 →MenuItem, 0x11e14e410, {{0.0, 401.0}, {220.0, 22.0}}, identifier: 'outline_mode', title: 'Outline Mode', Disabled
Path to element:
 →Application, 0x10f10cf00, pid: 90531, title: 'Vectornator', Disabled
  ↳MenuBar, 0x11e1178a0, {{0.0, 0.0}, {1440.0, 24.0}}
   ↳MenuBarItem, 0x11ce5bad0, {{401.0, 0.0}, {50.0, 24.0}}, title: 'View'
    ↳Menu, 0x11ce5bbe0, {{401.0, 24.0}, {220.0, 682.0}}
     ↳MenuItem, 0x11e14e410, {{0.0, 401.0}, {220.0, 22.0}}, identifier: 'outline_mode', title: 'Outline Mode', Disabled
```

So it doesn't have any "checkbox" item above or below it. `value` for it is empty :/ UI reads checkbox value from `UICommand.state`, but that doesn't seem to be exposed on `XCUIElement`.

Answer (score 0):

`outlineModeMenuItem.isEnabled` is the call you're looking for. It should return `true` when it is checked and `false` when it's not.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementattributes documents other attribute checks you might be interested in. I've not worked with a MenuItem before so it is possible `isSelected` might be what you're looking for.

Comment: If this doesn't work, you may want to looking into the `setAccessibilityValue()` function, which can be modified dynamically on click.

Comment: `isEnabled` tells you whether the button is enabled/disabled, i.e. greyed out or not. `isSelected` comes back as false no matter what the value is.

Comment: For checkboxes as far as I understood `value` is the property that works, but it doesn't work for `MenuItem`. 
I guess I could try `setAccessibilityValue`, but that sounds like a lot of overhead as I would have to modify every use of `UICommand`...

Comment: Bummer. I was worried the last resort was going to be the answer. Sorry I couldn’t be more help without a similar interface in front of me. And yeah, not the cleanest solution.

Comment: I'm just surprised how difficult the seemingly simple things are in XCTest...

Comment: It's definitely a immature tech, but there isn't much better :/

Comment: We used TestComplete in another company - it feels like we had way fewer issues for the problems that I'm solving. Although it's a completely different type of QA automation (i.e. it can be much more image-based).

Comment: Yeah, that’s the only real alternative (image-based); anything similar to this is just a layer built on top of XCUITest.

Comment: Turns out that there is `accessibilityValue` property on `UICommand`, but whatever value you set on it - it doesn't get retained. It doesn't even retain `accessibilityIdentifier` if I set that. I get an impression that `UICommand` properties are cloned at which point they loose all those values. I know that because I tried deriving `UICommand` class and the object "turns" from my class back to `UICommand` at some point. They definetelly didn't make it easy...

Answer (score 0):

So far everything points that it is not possible.

`UICommand` has `accessibilityValue` but it seems not to have any effect and actually loses value. This answer seems to confirm that too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60317536/217022

The only way I found was to modify the `title` when you know that you're running UI tests. Or expose these values in some other way unrelated to `UICommand`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that could be applied in your case but a hacky workaround you can use is to check the startX coordinate or the length of the MenuItem element to determine whether there is a checkmark there or not. I would not actually recommend it though because it is not very flexible and should probably be handled for all possible device widths